# Conditional formatting in rounded values

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Facing a trouble in Cognos 10, in my report I have to apply conditional formatting for values less than zero (except zero) as red, for which I am also applying round-off to zero decimals. Now the problem is values like `-0.1` are getting rounded-off to `0`, but also shown in red due to conditional formatting.

Is there any work around to show the rounded zero values in black?

Comment: Where are you applying the round off to zero decimals? You should just change the data format in the Cognos options, rather than applying a rounding function.

Comment: @toddnappi I have just changed data format in options for rounding. No other functions applied.

Comment: can you share you xml file

Comment: Did you change it at the model level, report level, or in the cell?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Sorry I could not share the xml.

Comment: @toddnappi Data Format is set at List Column Body level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rounding off the value on your condition on conditional style too. Like these:

round(([ColumnValue]*100),0) < 0

then set the foreground color or background color to red. Hope it helps.

Comment: But in Conditional formatting we can give only 'Range' and not an expression!

Comment: Use Advanced Conditional Style, that way you can specify the expression.